# how can i get the more than one data row value based on selected checkbox and store in useState (react-table-boostrap2)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap-table, use-state

I am new in reactjs and react-table-boostrap2.I am having a difficulties. I would like to get the data row value on the selected checkbox in the table, and what I do is I put state on the selectrow.onSelect props, as i try to click more than one checkbox  it only return object with one value, i would like to have an object with combine more than one value, but if im using selectRow.onSelectAll only applicable if select all the checkbox which is not on my requirement. kindly please help.

ps: really sorry english is not my first language.

sample code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import paginationFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator";
import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit";
import * as ReactBootStrap from "react-bootstrap";

const { SearchBar } = Search;

const App = () => {
  const [players, setPlayer] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState({});
  const getPlayerData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(
        "https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players-stats"
      );
      console.log(data);
      setPlayer(data.data);
      setLoading(true);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  const columns = [
    { dataField: "name", text: "Player Name" },
    { dataField: "points_per_game", text: "Points Per Game" },
    { dataField: "team_name", text: "Player Team" },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    getPlayerData();
  }, []);

  const selectRow = {
    mode: "checkbox",
    onSelect: (row, isSelect, rowIndex, e) => {
      setValue({ row }); // when console.log if click more than one the object does not combine the selected data row value
      console.log(row, isSelect);
    },
    onSelectAll: (isSelect, rows, e) => {
      console.log(isSelect);
      console.log(rows);
      console.log(e);
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loading ? (
        <ToolkitProvider
          keyField="name"
          data={players}
          columns={columns}
          search
        >
          {(props) => (
            <div>
              <h3>Input something at below input field:</h3>
              <SearchBar {...props.searchProps} />
              <hr />
              <BootstrapTable
                selectRow={selectRow}
                pagination={paginationFactory()}
                {...props.baseProps}
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </ToolkitProvider>
      ) : (
        <ReactBootStrap.Spinner animation="border" />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv8lJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make such logic: if object is already presented - remove, else - add? You should give variables better names than "value", for example selectedRows or something like this.

```
 const handleSelectRow = (e, columnIndex, rowIndex, row) => {
    if (!(value.some(item => row.name === item.name))) {
        const selectedData = {
            name: row.name,
            points: row.points_per_game,
            team: row.team_name,
        };
        setValue(value => [...value, selectedData]);
    } else {
        setValue(value.filter(item => item.name !== row.name));
    }
  };
```